Connect our SQL Server to a remote SQL Server
I would like to have my SQL Server connect (read-only) to a SQL Server at one of our vendors, pull data from it and populate a table on my SQL Server every 15 minutes. Is this possible? I have web-searched for an answer, but I can't seem to formulate the question well enough to get an answer.

There are several ways to accomplish this, one being replication that @Charles Burge mentioned in his answer, but there other ways as well, including the creation of a linked server and using various technologies such as SSIS, Agents, or stored procedures, to move data.

The concept you are looking for may be "linked server", and it is a feature of MS SQL Server. See the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16 .
You setup a linked server, and then you can query that server in a normal SQL stament as in select * from <server>.<database>.<schema>.<table>.
Then you write a stored procedure that has the relevant statement in it, and exec that SPROC from an SQl Server Agent job.

This sounds like what we need. Will try this next week and report back.

What you're talking about is called database replication.  If you search that term, you can find some setup guides.  There are third-party tools for for replication, but I think you can also set it up in SQL server.
